# Diferenças entre System.out x System.err x System.in?

Tags: java

Não encontrei nenhum debate sobre essa pergunta aqui na comunidade então resolvi criar esse tópico. Segue uma dúvida bem comentada entre os iniciantes na linguagem Java quando se trata de manipulação de dados.

- *Qual a diferença entre os três comandos?*
- *Qual deve ser utilizado em cada caso?*
- *E qual o mais eficaz?*

Comment: Já que ninguem linkou a documentação: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html

Comment: Muito obrigado pela edição @diegofm, acabei esquecendo de citar as perguntas separadamente como tópicos aqui!

Answer (score 4):

**System.out** é o output padrão do sistema que você está usando. **System.err** é o output padrão de erros do sistema. Em uma aplicação console normal, ambos provavelmente irão printar no console. Mas você pode reconfigurar os outputs para, por exemplo, fazer os erros printarem em um arquivo de texto, e deixar o **System.out** printar na tela.

Já o **System.in** é o padrão de input do sistema, do tipo `InputStream`. Ele já é aberto, e pronto para receber dados. Tipicamente, ele corresponde ao teclado ou a qualquer fonte de dados especificados ou pelo ambiente, ou pelo usuários.

**System.in** --> Recebe dados

**System.out** e **System.err** --> Fazem o output de dados. Podem ser reconfigurados para escrever em diferentes lugares

Answer (score 1):

#### System.in

Entrada padrão do tipo `InputStream`, geralmente conectada ao teclado em programas orientados a terminal/console.

#### System.out

Saída padrão do tipo `PrintStream`. Geralmente envia os dados gravado nela para o console/terminal. Muito utilizada por programas baseados em console como ferramentas de linha de comando (`grep`, `find`).

#### System.err

Saída de erro do tipo `PrintStream`. Funciona como o System.out, exceto que é usada para enviar mensagens de erro.

Em uma aplicação Java orientada ao terminal, ambas as saídas serão a mesma (a linha de comando), mas pode-se reconfigurá-las para que Sistem.out continue imprimindo no terminal, e System.err escreva em um arquivo, por exemplo.

Esta reconfiguração pode ser feita diretamente no terminal conforme [estes](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html) exemplos.

Comment: System.in não é só para entrada de teclado.

Comment: Sei disso @diegofm, por isso deixei claro com "geralmente" e "programas orientados a terminal". Sei que é usado em redirecionamentos e pipes.